# SwiftUI unusual crash: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: !CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this unusual crash which happens completely randomly (like 1/10 times).
I have a **View** which contains various **sections of products** (list of products divided by sections), and sometimes if I try to import another section of products by calling an API, I get this crash. When I restart the app I can see all the sections, but the section that I added that caused the crash has 0 products (only the name of the section is visible, but 0 elements). The products are correctly fetched (I can see the Xcode log of the event succeeded). The View which contains the Lists of products is structured like this:

```
List($dataSource, id: \.id) { data in
    ListView(sectionName: data.sectionName, section: data.section, products: data.products)
}
```

While each ListView contains the product cells this way:

```
ForEach($products, id: \.id) {product in
    ProductCellView(product: product)
}
```

The crash can occur when I navigate to "import another list" and I select another list of products to import. Before coming back to my MainView, which contains the lists, the app crashes.

I tried to fix the crash by adjusting the app concurrency with async await, in order to wait the services to fetch all the products before coming back to the main view, but this seems like a problem linked to the UI itself. Can somebody help me? thanks!

Comment: how about filtering out the categories with 0 products before feeding them to view?